# Too much space after `\start...`

Tags: spacing, context

I have this file:

```
\newdimen\cslhangindent
\cslhangindent=1.5em
\definestartstop [cslreferences] [
        before={%
        \setupnarrower[left=\cslhangindent]
        \startnarrower[left]%
        \setupindenting[-\leftskip,yes,first]%
        \indentation%
      },
      after=\stopnarrower,
    ]

\starttext

\section{Some title}

\input ward

\section{References}

\startcslreferences

\dorecurse{10}{\dorecurse{10}{This is a Test. }\par}

\stopcslreferences

\stoptext
```

The skip after the `\section{References}` is bigger than after `\section{Some title}`. Why is that? If I delete the empty line after `\startcslreferences`, the skips are identical.

Is there a way to take care of this through `\definestartstop`?

Comment: @JohnKormylo: The tag `context` already specifies that. Those who don't wish to see ConTeXt questions  can add it too the list of their ignored tags.

Comment: @Denis: Didn't you ask the same question on the context mailing list yesterday and receive a reply from Hans. At the very least, you should link to [that question](https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2019/096364.html) and explain why the solution by Hans doesn't work for your situation.

Comment: Yes and no. Asked on the mailing list but no answer from Hans. (Well it did not come through)

Comment: Ok. Hans's answer is there obviously. Don't know why I didn't see that answer... sorry for the noise

Comment: @Aditya - Thank you!  It took me a while and some searching through meta Latex, but I finally discovered how to make context an ignored tag (you hover over the tag).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `\indentation` statement which immediately forces the indentation box to be placed, but you only want the indentation when the paragraph is started, so instead use `\doindentation`.

```latex
\definemeasure[cslhangindent][1.5em]
\definestartstop
  [cslreferences]
  [before={%
     \setupnarrower[left=\measure{cslhangindent}]
     \startnarrower[left]%
     \setupindenting[-\leftskip,yes,first]%
     \doindentation%
   },
   after=\stopnarrower]

\starttext

\section{Some title}

\input ward

\section{References}

\startcslreferences

\dorecurse{10}{\dorecurse{10}{This is a Test. }\par}

\stopcslreferences

\stoptext
```

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful indeed. But were would I have to look to find that kind of information?

Comment: @Denis You have to use ConTeXt for long enough to know about such tricks.  I always learn new things by reading the mailing list.

Comment: Ok. But there is nothing like `\donoindentation`. Right? @Henri Menke

Comment: @Denis I think that's just `\noindentation`.